# extract value from xml in mysql

Tags: mysql, xml

i am trying to extract values from xml. i am getting problem when xml has attribute.
like following Stored Procedure

```sql
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `excel`.`insert_items` $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `insert_items`()
BEGIN
SET @xml = '<items><item>
        <value columntype="0">Single Line Text_01</value>
    <value columntype="1">Single Line Text_12341</value>
    <value columntype="2">Single Line Text_21</value>
    <value columntype="3">Single Line Text_31</value>
    <value columntype="4">Single Line Text_41</value>
    </item>
</items>';
SELECT @columntype, ExtractValue(@xml, 'items/item/value[items/item/value/@columntype=0]');    
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: What is the problem here on extracting ?

Answer (score 11):

To get a value of an element with attribute `columntype="0"`

```sql
SELECT ExtractValue(@xml, 'items/item/value[@columntype=0]') value;
```

Output:

```
|               VALUE |
-----------------------
| Single Line Text_01 |
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/12093)**

Comment: What if I have this XML:

`<items>
 <item>
     <value1>Single Line Text_01</value>
     <value2>Single Line Text_12341</value>
     <value3>Single Line Text_21</value>
     <value4>Single Line Text_31</value>
     <value5>Single Line Text_41</value>
    </item>
</items>`
How can I extract values individually in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Following code will print value of **columntype** and **value** :

```
 DELIMITER $$
    DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `TEST`$$
    CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `TEST`(IN XMLINPUT TEXT)
    BEGIN
    DECLARE VALUECOUNT INT UNSIGNED;
    DECLARE VALUE INT UNSIGNED;
    DECLARE I INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 1;
    SET VALUECOUNT:=EXTRACTVALUE(XMLINPUT, 'COUNT(/items/item/value)');
    SELECT VALUECOUNT; -- print 5
    WHILE (I <= VALUECOUNT) DO 
        SELECT EXTRACTVALUE(XMLINPUT, '/items/item/value[$I]/@columntype[1]'); -- will print columntype tag
        SELECT EXTRACTVALUE(XMLINPUT, '/items/item/value[$I]'); -- will print value tag     
    SET I:= I+1;
    END WHILE;

    END$$DELIMITER ;
```