# MySQL ExtractValue() from xml with entity

Tags: mysql, xml, entity, mariadb

It is possible to extract values with entities in MySQL or MariaDB?

```
SET @xml = '<!ENTITY foo "foofoofoo" ><bar>&foo;</bar>';
SELECT ExtractValue(@xml, 'bar')
```

This query returns null(or &foo;)

Comment: look at this link. this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16475926/extract-value-from-xml-in-mysql

Comment: there is no problem without using entites